# Can this trigger result in infinite recursion in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a SQL Server 2008 R2 database that has a table called 'xyz'. This table has the following trigger, in which I populate the username for an inserted record by getting it from another database on same server.

**My question is**: Can this trigger cause the same trigger to be executed so we end up with unecessary recursion? I did not find any such thing in my tests, but just wanted to be sure since I am completely new to the world of triggers.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trig_UpdateProduct]
ON [dbo].[xyz]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN

  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  UPDATE xyz
  SET UserName = pu.UserName
  FROM INSERTED i
  INNER JOIN SampleDB.dbo.ProductUser pu
    ON i.ProductId = pu.ProductId
  WHERE xyz.ProductId = i.ProductId

END
```

Comment: The trigger should not cause recursion.  Even though the name of the trigger is `trig_UpdateProduct`, it is an `AFTER INSERT` trigger, so it only fires for inserts (of course).  The trigger tsql performs an update.  Something else of note is that `Recursive Triggers Enabled` is a property that can be set at the database level.  In SSMS, right-click a db and select properties.  Click "Options" in the "Select a page" pane and you'll see a place to set the property to True/False.

Comment: @DMason, Can you please post this, so I can mark your response as an answer? Thanks.

Comment: @DMason, So  if the above trigger inserted another record into xyz , it would not fire a recursion when Recursive Trigger Enabled = false?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @DMason, Thanks. I am learning new things about triggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trigger should not cause recursion. Even though the name of the trigger is `trig_UpdateProduct`, it is an `AFTER INSERT` trigger, so it only fires for inserts (of course). The trigger tsql performs an update.

Something else of note is that `Recursive Triggers Enabled` is a property that can be set at the database level. In SSMS, right-click a db and select properties. Click "Options" in the "Select a page" pane and you'll see a place to set the property to True/False.